# Layout Widget Error: "You were unable to take control of the document"

Tags: apostrophe-cms

## Hello Apostrophe CMS Wizards

I was reading the tutorial found here: https://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/getting-started/layout-widgets.html

It says:

> An alternative to `contextualOnly`, `skipInitialModal` lets you skip the widget manager modal when the widget is created (like `contextualOnly`) but preserves the Edit UI for later use. This is useful for widgets that have secondary configuration, like setting a background color.

This is EXACTLY the kind of functionality that I want to expose for my users. I have already built a much more complex version of the code found in the gist above, but the simpler version still has the same error that I am experiencing so I am including the code for that here.

Essentially, I want to have an editing dialog for my custom layout widget that allows them to change the background color, decide whether or not to add a background image, decide how that background image is displayed, all without having to touch code.

### The Problem

After saving the changes to my custom widget, you are unable to make changes to what is inside my widget's areas. Instead, it spits out an error telling you that `You were unable to take control of the document.`

You can get the wanted functionality back if you refresh the page, but obviously that is not ideal.

What am I missing here?

### Example Code

You'll notice that the code below is only slightly modified example code for the tutorial page above.

Here is the simple widget's `widget.html` file:

```
<div class="two-column">
    <div class="column-left">
        {{ apos.area(data.widget, 'areaLeft', {
            widgets: {
                'apostrophe-images': {}
            }
        }) }}
    </div>
    <div class="column-right">
        {{ apos.area(data.widget, 'areaRight', {
            widgets: {
                'apostrophe-images': {}
            }
        }) }}
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is the simple widget's `index.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
    extend: 'apostrophe-widgets',
    label: 'Double Content',
    skipInitialModal: true,
    addFields: [
      {
        name: 'areaLeft',
        type: 'area',
        label: 'Left Area',
        contextual: true
      },
      {
        name: 'areaRight',
        type: 'area',
        label: 'Right Area',
        contextual: true
      }
    ]
  };
```

### UPDATE 1

As suggested, I cloned [this repo](https://github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe-samples) and modified the `One Column` widget to match the setup mentioned above. For completeness, I've included my changes to the code here. I've made no other changes to the repo's code.

```
module.exports = {
  extend: 'apostrophe-widgets',
  label: 'One Column',
  // contextualOnly: true, // removed
  skipInitialModal:true, // added
  addFields: [
    {
      name: 'one',
      type: 'area',
      contextual:true, // added
    }
  ]
};
```

### RESULT

Still have the same problem.

If it helps, the version of ApostropheCMS used in the repo above is: 2.58.0

### Look at this

I'm new here, so actually embedding images here is not allowed, but this should still work. Have a look:

[screen capture gif of failure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJXEN.gif)

### UPDATE 2

With the new [update](https://github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe/releases/tag/2.59.0), everything appears to have been fixed!

Comment: Is your version of Apostrophe up to date? Fixes relating to this were made not long ago. Also, check out the working example here:

https://github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe-samples

If you can reproduce the problem in that project, let us know the exact steps so we can get a handle on it. Thanks!

Comment: @TomBoutell Thanks for the response! I've updated the post to reflect your suggestions. Any thoughts?

Comment: I was able to reproduce these bugs and have opened up two tickets regarding them https://github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe/issues/1428 https://github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe/issues/1429

Comment: That's great! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original issue reported has been fixed in this commit https://github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe/pull/1430 .. it is currently in `master` and will be published to npm within a week or so.

Answer (score 0):

A fix for this lingering issue has been published to npm as Apostrophe 2.59.0. This new release addresses this problem in the case where the widget is edited via a modal and *also* has contextual nested editing happening on the page.